# Google doc 100+ pages: how to automatically makes it load all the page (without having to wait)

Tags: google-docs, google-chrome

I'm working on a 100+ pages google doc in chrome.

Each time I open it, I need to wait for all the pages to load (I see the page increasing when I hover the scroll bar on the right). The problem is that it takes a while (several minutes) to reach the last page where I need to go. And I can't do anything else: when the tab isn't active, it stop loading. So I really need to wait for the page to load.

And since on chrome the pined tab aren't protected from closure or changing URL, it often close or goes to another page. So I have to wait again for the document to load to work.

**Is there a way to make this document load by itself, without having to wait in front of it?**

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling offline access

From: [Work on Google Docs, Sheets, & Slides offline](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6388102?hl=en)

> Turn on offline for Google Docs, Sheets, and Slides You can save the
>   most recently opened documents on your computer. To turn on offline
>   access:
>
> 1. On your computer, open the Google Docs, Sheets, or Slides home screen.
> 2. In the top left, click Menu [image: Menu].
> 3. Click Settings.
> 4. Turn Offline on.
> 5. When you turn on offline access for Docs, Sheets, Slides, or Drive, it will be turned on for the others, too.

Comment: thanks but it was already enabled

Comment: @J.Does try to open the document while your PC is disconnected